# How to create a standalone Java executable for Windows?

Tags: java, executable

I'm very new to Java programming, and I don't know how it works, but I do have some experience with PHP, Javascript, Pascal and some C++.

I've searched all day for Java programming tutorials and I've found some interesting tutorials  but only about the basics. I don't want to create console programs and to learn about variables and loops.

I need a tutorial that shows me how to create a program in Java, something that opens a window with some tabs and multiple clickable buttons. A program that starts with a .exe file, not a .class and what contains lots of .jar files.

Comment: Why would you ever want to tie your Java program to only one specific platform (Windows) with an EXE file? JAR files are executabele on almost every operating system platform the world is aware of: Windows, Unix, Linux, Mac, Solaris, etc. Wouldn't you like to gain world domination with your program?

Comment: There are lots of reasons.  Watching your program show up in the service manager / process list (instead of java).  Guaranteeing a specific (bundled) JVM version, despite the environment, etc.

Comment: @BalusC: Hard to tell, but I think he's asking how to create an executable GUI program and is using `.exe` as a proxy for `executable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to write a GUI program using Java.  Have a look at Java Swing.  There are a ton of resources available via google, here's one:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JNI to launch a JVM internally from a C / C++ program.

[Here's an example.](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/c.html)

Once you have the JVM up, provided you passed the correct parameters to it, you should see the JVM bootstrap the Java code and start from your main method.

Answer (score 0):

The file ist called `java.exe`? But in earnest: You can find so called wrapper-scripts on the net, that can do almost what you want.

You also might want to take a look at: http://jnc.mtsystems.ch/

Answer (score 0):

For a simple program that shows a Swing GUI, you will not need additional `.jar` files. Java compiles to `.class` files which you can pack to a `.jar` file yourself. This you can execute with a batch file or use a Java launcher like [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in graphical user interface for Java you should read about the Java swing framework in the `javax.swing` package.
As far as making a standard windows executable (.exe), it's a bit more complicated but you can do it.  Generally, when you want to distribute your program you'll turn it into a .jar file and be able to execute it via:

```
java -jar MyProgram.jar
```

You can create a short .exe in C/C++ that executes this line.  You could also create a .bat script that does the same.  Keep in mind that you must have Java installed for your program to run, so when you distribute your program to other people, they will have to install Java first.